# Eloquent ORM many to many relationship through mapping table

Tags: php, orm, eloquent

I am new to eloquent and I can't seem to find an example of creating a many to many relationship through a mapping table.  Here is the table structure in question:

ResultInfo Table

- ResultID PrimaryKey
- some other fields

ResultInfoMapping Table

- ResultsInfoMappingsID PrimaryKey
- ResultID  ForeignKey to ResultsInfo Table
- ServiceID ForeignKey to Service Table

ServiceKeywords Table

- ServiceID PrimaryKey
- some other fields

I have a model for each table such that

```
class Result extends Model {
    protected $table = 'The table name';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ResultId';

    public function keywords() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Models\ServiceKeywords',   Models\ResultsInfoMappings');
    }
}


class ResultInfoMappings extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'The table name';
}
class ServiceKeywords extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'The table name';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ServiceID';
}
```

I feel like this must be common but I can't find an example of how to do this and have not been successful. Thanks

better example here
http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: first, remove that colon after `Models\ResultsInfoMappings`

Comment: I apoligize, I had some issue using stack overflow markdown. My problem isn't a syntax error, please consider what I have posted as psuedo code only.

Comment: Although this is an old post, Nonetheless, did you try something like so: `public function keyword(){ return $this->belongsToMany(ServiceKeywords::class, 'ResultInfoMapping_table');}`